# Android class 'GeofencingClient' doesn't exist?

Tags: java, android, geofencing

I'm attempting to follow the [Android geofencing guide](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#java), but I immedietely get stuck when I try to declare a `GeofencingClient` variable:

[image: Cannot resolve symbol GeofencingClient]

Normally I would be able to just press Alt+Enter and select "Import class", but this option isn't available here:

[image: No import class option]

Does the `GeofencingClient` class exist anymore? Do I need to install some third party library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[GeofencingClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingClient) is part of Google Play Services. You need to add the following  dependency to the build.gradle file of the module, then you will be able to import the class in your code:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingClient` ...

This depends on [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
}
```